# How to use timestamp in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am new in stackoverflow.
Also, please forgive me for my english.

I have a question about using timestamp in MySQL stored proc.
I am using MySQL 5 and MySQLdb Python module (Python version 2.6).
Here is a code to create my stored procedure:

```
def create_procedure_sum_shift ():
    global cursor

    cursor.execute("CREATE PROCEDURE `sum_shift`\
    (IN s_Time DATETIME, IN e_Time DATETIME)\
    BEGIN\
    SET @q = concat('SELECT * FROM trig_test WHERE `t_stamp`>=',\
    s_Time,' AND `t_stamp` <= ', e_Time);\
    PREPARE query FROM @q;\
    EXECUTE query;\
    deallocate prepare query;\
    END;")
```

When I am trying to create this proc, everything is ok.
But, when i am calling this proc, I am getting an error.
Here is a call of this procedure:

```
def call_sum_shift(startDate, endDate):
    global cursor
    cursor.execute("call sum_shift(DATE('%s'),DATE('%s'));" % (startDate, endDate))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    discr = cursor.description
    return rows,discr
```

startDate (and endDate) I get this:

```
time = datetime.datetime(2012, 07, 25, 8, 00, 00)
startDate = str (time)
```

Here is the an error:

```
..._mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError:(1064,"You have an error...for the right syntax to    use near '00:00:00 AND `t_stamp` <= 2012-07-25 00:00:00` at line 1)
```

Where is my mistake? If it possible, please give an example, of using  the "timestamp" in MySQL stored proc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `concat` you are generating a query string containing textual representation of DateTime which needs to be  enclosed in `'`. This is not being done.

Comment: Also beware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your stored procedure.